# Portrait Lock orientation mode problem

Tags: ios

When I turn my iphone 5 sideways it has no problem going into landscape mode but when I try to lock it, it goes back to portrait mode

Answer (score 1):

Portrait Lock is just that, it locks the screen in portrait.

There is no global Landscape Lock, it can only be done in-app.